# Object to separate KeyValue Pair collections

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, key-value

I have a challenge where I need to take any object and flatten into a key value pair format

This is working really well for simple classes, and even classes where I have other classes within it

Looking at an example,

```
public class Buyer
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address")]public string Address { get; set; }        
    [JsonProperty("lastPurchase")]public Purchase LastPurchase { get; set; }

    public Buyer()
    {
        Name = "Joe Bloggs";
        Address = "An adddress somewhere";

        AllPurchases = new List<Purchase>()
        {
            new Purchase() {PurchaseAmount = 100, PurchaseDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-01-01")},
            new Purchase() {PurchaseAmount = 100, PurchaseDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-01-01")}
        };

        LastPurchase = new Purchase() {PurchaseAmount = 100, PurchaseDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-01-01")};
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Purchase> AllPurchases { get; set; }

}

public class Purchase
{
    public DateTime PurchaseDateTime { get; set; }
    public double PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I have the code below which is my current implementation

```
var buyer = new Buyer();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(buyer);
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = obj.Descendants()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(s => s.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Path,
                p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                    ? null : p.Value.ToString()));


var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                         {
                             Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                             ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                         };
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, serializerSettings);
Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

This generates the Json below which is perfect

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  {
    "key": "address",
    "value": "An adddress somewhere"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseDateTime",
    "value": "01/01/2018 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseAmount",
    "value": "100"
  }
]
```

Things get tricky when I introduce serialising the list by removing JsonIgnore

Now I get

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  {
    "key": "address",
    "value": "An adddress somewhere"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseDateTime",
    "value": "01/01/2018 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseAmount",
    "value": "100"
  },
  {
    "key": "allPurchases",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "key": "allPurchases[0].PurchaseDateTime",
    "value": "01/01/2017 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": "allPurchases[0].PurchaseAmount",
    "value": "100"
  },
  {
    "key": "allPurchases[1].PurchaseDateTime",
    "value": "01/01/2018 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": "allPurchases[1].PurchaseAmount",
    "value": "100"
  }
]
```

This has obviously happened because my logic doesnt have anything specific in it for processing lists

How can I change my logic so that AllPurchases is a key value pair collection with the key being allPurchases[0], allPurchases[1] and the value is separate key value collection, which would avoid key names like allPurchases[0].PurchaseAmount etc?

I need to keep the solution generic so that it will flatten any object into this structure

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you want the following.
Values and objects not in the array to be transferred to json objects in form of {key:"propertyPath", value:"valueTostring"}
Sub Objects to arrays of of key value pairs.
Arrays to indexed  {key:"property[index]", value:"valueTostringOrObjectKeyValueArray"} 
The following

```
        var result = GetItmes(obj);


        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>> GetItmes(in JToken token, string path = "")
        {
            return token switch
            {
                JObject jObject => from prop in token.Children<JProperty>()
                                   from child in GetItmes(prop.Value, string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? prop.Name : $"{path}.{prop.Name}")
                                   select child,
                JArray jArray => from item in jArray.Select((t, i) => (t, i))
                                 select new KeyValuePair<string, object>($"{path}[{item.i}]",GetItmes(item.t)),
                JValue jValue => new[] { 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>(path, (object)jValue?.ToString()) 
                },
                _ => Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(),
            };
        }
```

Will create

```
    [
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  {
    "key": "address",
    "value": "An adddress somewhere"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseDateTime",
    "value": "1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastPurchase.PurchaseAmount",
    "value": "100"
  },
  {
    "key": "AllPurchases[0]",
    "value": [
      {
        "key": "PurchaseDateTime",
        "value": "1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        "key": "PurchaseAmount",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "AllPurchases[1]",
    "value": [
      {
        "key": "PurchaseDateTime",
        "value": "1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        "key": "PurchaseAmount",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This code is recursive and unoptimized I am sure there could be a much more efficient way to do this.

For

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetItmes(JToken token, string path = "")
        {
            switch (token)
            {
                case JObject jObject:
                    return from prop in token.Children<JProperty>()
                           from child in GetItmes(prop.Value, string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? prop.Name : $"{path}.{prop.Name}")
                           select child;
                case JArray jArray:
                    return from item in jArray.Select((t, i) => (t, i))
                           select new KeyValuePair<string, object>($"{path}[{item.i}]", GetItmes(item.t));
                case JValue jValue:
                    return new[] {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>(path, (object)jValue?.ToString())
                };
                default: return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
            };
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think I can use this as I get a C# version error saying recursive patterns not available in C 7.3 and I dont think our piplines would support c# 8

Comment: Could you tell me tell me the version? This query can easily be written in any c# version.Its just shorter this way.

Comment: I’m using 7.3 with .net core 2.2 and full 4.7.2

Comment: Added 7.3 version just changed the switch.